# check if a date falls on the third week of the month VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date

Was wondering if there is a function build in with VB.net that can tell me which Number of week it belongs to.

ie. 
        2013-05-10 = "Part of 2nd Week'
        2013-05-31 = "Part of 5h week"

does the datetimepicker come with a function for this?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare WeekOfYear of the first day of selected month with the WeekOfYear of the selected date.

```
Dim dtDate1 As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 5, 10)
MsgBox(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, dtDate1, FirstDayOfWeek.System) - DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, New DateTime(dtDate1.Year, dtDate1.Month, 1), FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 1)

Dim dtDate2 As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 5, 31)
MsgBox(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, dtDate2, FirstDayOfWeek.System) - DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, New DateTime(dtDate2.Year, dtDate2.Month, 1), FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 1)
```

Or as a function:

```
Function GetWeekInMonth(dtDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim DateWeekNumber As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, dtDate, FirstDayOfWeek.System)
    Dim MonthStartWeek As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, New DateTime(dtDate.Year, dtDate.Month, 1), FirstDayOfWeek.System)
    Return DateWeekNumber - MonthStartWeek + 1
End Function
```

But this would be really great to add as an extension to the date-object:

```
Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function GetWeekInMonth(dtDate As Date) As Integer
        Dim DateWeekNumber As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, dtDate, FirstDayOfWeek.System)
        Dim MonthStartWeek As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, New DateTime(dtDate.Year, dtDate.Month, 1), FirstDayOfWeek.System)
        Return DateWeekNumber - MonthStartWeek + 1
    End Function

End Module
```

Now you can use .GetWeekInMonth on every date object in your project.

```
Dim weeknr As Integer = CDate("2013-05-31").GetWeekInMonth
```

Comment: Added some examples to your answer. I love Extensions! ;)